# Create Index to month of timestamp only mongoldb

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am new to MongoDB. I have a MongoDB database which has documents of each minute(timestamp field). To optimise the query performance I created a compound index:

```
db.data.createIndex({dId:1,ts:-1})
```

But my query has:

```
"$match":{ dId:  deviceId,year_agg:year_input,month_agg:month_input }
```

I wish to create index on only month of the timestamp so that the query time is reduced. Is that possible?

Comment: No. You can only index "discreet fields". Sounds like you need a separate field for "month" if queries on that irrespective of the year are important to you.

Comment: If you have not only the month, but also the year in the query, this can be turned into a range scan on the timestamp field.

Comment: Oh, thank you for the information and help.